# Second HDD not recognized until clicked

Tags: hard-drive

As an example, whenever I try to download something on the hard drive, my pc wont even recognize having a second HDD plugged in until I go to Files and click on the hard drive in "Other Locations"

Comment: lsblk, /dev, disks, gparted & others must recognize the drive if it's mountable, the title / question should probably be clarified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, as your system is not currently auto mounting that external drive. You can set your external drive to automount on system startup by either editing the `/etc/fstab` file and adding a entry like this:

`UUID=DRIVE_UUID MOUNT_POINT FILESYSTEM ARGUMENTS 0 1`

or Add using `Disks` tools gui.

[image: How to automount drives]

Comment: +1, but how about checking if the drive is powered up & spinning, or if it will go to sleep after X minutes too?

Comment: from his problem description, i was sure that the problem is not about operating system not recognizing the drive, but instead only auto mounting the second drive.